# handling double username in mysql and php

Tags: php, pdo

I'm writing my own implementation of an API. One of the resources of this API is `/user`, I can `POST` a `JSON` string to this, parse it and send it to a `UserService` which has an `addUser` method. Now obviously I can't allow two users to have the same username. This is what I have to so far.

```
protected function handlePost() {
    $user = json_decode($this->getRequest()->getRequestData(), true);

    try {
        $createdUserId = $this->userService->addUser(
            $user['username'],
            $user['password'],
            $user['typeId'],
            $user['companyId']
        );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->getResponse()->setStatus(102);
    }

    if ($createdUserId)
        $this->getResponse()->setStatus(101);

    $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
}
```

This function is called after the HTTP request has been parsed. As you can see, I get the `$user` object in an associative array. I then use these values as parameters to the `$this->userService->addUser` method.

This is the `addUser()` method:

```
public function addUser($username, $password, $type, $companyId) {
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO app_user
                                (username, password, typeId, companyId)
                                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $userAdded = $sth->execute(array($username, md5($password), $type, $companyId));

    return ($userAdded)
        ? $this->dbh->lastInsertId()
        : null;
}
```

Now if the `$sth->execute` fails for some reason, I return null (and neither status code 101 or 102 will be returned, I'm aware of this). But if a username already exists PDO throws an exception, which I catch in my `handlePost()` method above.

My problem with this is of course that a username which has already been taken is not exceptional and should not be handled this way but I don't really know how I should handle it?

It must remain possible for me to be able to distinguish between a unique constraint being triggered and some other (maybe concurrency issue) being triggered so I can send the appropriate status code back to the consumer of the API.

An obvious solution would be to check if the username exists in a a separate query but for obvious reasons I would prefer to keep the calls to the database limited.

How can I solve this elegantly? If I do have to use exceptions, is there a list of specific PDO exceptions so that I don't have to use the generic `PDOException`?

Comment: Tell me if i'm getting you right - You want to check if user exists in DB without using SQL?

Comment: Your code says you're writing an API, but your text says you're implementing an API. I'm confused!

Comment: @Yehonatan No no, I know that's impossible :p, I just want to know if there's a way to check it, without having to use exceptions to deal with it and limit the number of queries to the DB to preferably 1.

Comment: @Adnan, I'm writing the consumer and provider part myself.

Comment: Two options, do another query, or set the username to a unique key and detect insertion failure.

Comment: @pEkvo You can't perform an insert and a select in the same request, but you can use a stored procedure to minify the roundtrips between PHP and the sql server. But this has a drawback : part of your logic is in the SQL server, and not in your Application anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you concerned enough with performance (i.e. minimizing queries against the database) that you wouldn't just check the existence of the user name in the database before trying to do an insert?  You might find this easier logic to follow than trying to catch the Exception and figure out if there really is an exception or not based on the number of rows effected with the last query or similar.

I would also add that if you want to make it not an exception you could add ON DUPLICATE KEY logic to your insert.

Comment: You're right in theory but as PHP has a share nothing architecture, you can't avoid 2 requests running in parallel, trying to insert the same username, unless you create a  global mechanism to lock the username between 2 PHP requests.

Comment: @BenjaminDubois, using this approach, couldn't I just put the check username and insert (if not yet found) in a transaction?

Comment: @pEkvo yes ! with a stored procedure which is a single transaction :) but you need to write it directly in SQL, and call it with PHP.

Comment: @BenjaminDubois, ok thanks for your help. I'm going to accept this answer as it's what I was most looking for, but your own answer was helpful as well after checking the PDO documentation so I will upvote it :)

Comment: The chance of two requests with the same exact username at the same exact time are probably pretty minimal unless you are talking about an extremely high volume service. In which case, you are correct, you probably wouldn't want to make two separate queries in the first place (thus my initial comment about performance).

Answer (score 1):

PDO should not send an exception for an integrity constraint violation if your not using the ERRMODE_EXCEPTION  in your PDO constructor.

In that case, you must call the method PDOStatement::errorCode() or PDOStatement::errorInfo()

to get the details of the error and see if it's an integrity constraint violation or a real problem.

Comment: I have the ERRMODE_EXCEPTION mode enabled at the moment, would you say it's discouraged to use this in production? (Which would then obviously force me to alter my approach)

Comment: @pEkvo Yes, for me, you shouldn't use ERRMODE_EXCEPTION in prod: PDO will keep sending exceptions when a big error happens (like when the db server is unreachable), but not for SQL constraints violation, which are not exceptional in an API...